# Кнопка "показать ещё"

Tags: javascript

Есть 100 элементов с блоками.
Необходимо показать на странице первые 10 блоков.
При повторном клике на кнопку, показывать следующие 10 блоков.

```js
var box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
console.log(box);

btn = addEventListener("click", function() {
  box.slice(0, 9);

})
```

```css
.wrapper-boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<button>Show 10</button>
```

https://codepen.io/vitalikdark/pen/vYOXNvW

Comment: Как показывать 10+ элементов?

Comment: Вариантов на вскидку как минимум 3. Как Вы пробовали делать? И пробовали ли вообще?

Comment: тож кинул вам кодепен с тем что на работал вы вооюбще  смотрели??????

Comment: Код нужно вставлять сразу в вопрос

Comment: показывать следующие - это скрыть уже показанные и показать новые или добавить к показанным новые, чтобы отображались сразу несколько десятков?

Comment: Показывать это значить показать ещё +10 блоков

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Всем блокам дать класс-невидимку, при каждом клике собрать все элементы с этим классом и с первых N элементов убрать невидимку, дать другой класс со стилями:

```js
var more = document.querySelectorAll('.more');

for (var i = 0; i < more.length; i++) {
  more[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    var showPerClick = 3;
    
    var hidden = this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('div.hidden');
    for (var i = 0; i < showPerClick; i++) {
      if (!hidden[i]) return this.outerHTML = "";

      hidden[i].classList.add('box');
      hidden[i].classList.remove('hidden');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.wrapper-boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  margin: 1px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <!-- какой-нибудь общий родитель для кнопки и блоков -->
  <button class="more">Show 3</button>
  <hr>
  <div class="wrapper-boxes">
    <div class="hidden"></div><div class="hidden"></div><div class="hidden"></div>
    <div class="hidden"></div><div class="hidden"></div><div class="hidden"></div>
    <div class="hidden"></div><div class="hidden"></div><div class="hidden"></div>
    <div class="hidden"></div><div class="hidden"></div><div class="hidden"></div>
    <div class="hidden"></div><div class="hidden"></div><div class="hidden"></div>
    <div class="hidden"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Очень интересно, откуда вдруг два минуса))

Comment: @OPTIMUS PRIME Вот очень много людей с негативным предвзятым отношением. Я всё тоже стараюсь не обращать на них внимание, но они постоянно портят всё настроение. От меня тоже большой плюс.

Answer (score 13):

Codepen я смотрел. 
Вот только попытки Ваши закончились на `box.slice(0,9)`
Это потом Вы хоть что-то добавили. 
Так как Grundy сделал мне выговор, который мы ещё обсудим, решил добавить ответ.

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        var box=document.getElementsByClassName('box');
        var btn=document.getElementById('button');
        for (let i=10;i<box.length;i++) {
            box[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        var countD = 10;
        btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
            var box=document.getElementsByClassName('box');
            countD += 10;
            if (countD <= box.length){
                for(let i=0;i<countD;i++){
                    box[i].style.display = "block";
                }
            }

        })
    }
```

```css
    body {
        background: blue;
    }
    .wrapper-boxes {
        display: flex;
        text-align: center;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 79%;
    }
    .box {
        margin: 5px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: orange;
        border-radius: 3px;
    }
    button {
        width: 78%;
        line-height: 40px;
        background-color: orange;
        border: 4px solid #fff;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-boxes">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<button id="button">Show 10</button>
```

Comment: Когда там @Grundy тебе выговор делал? :)

Comment: `box` - можно один раз получить, не нужно проходить по уже видимым элементам при каждом нажатии кнопки

Answer (score 7):

Вот красивое решение. В скрипте можно указать, какое количество элементов выводить. Когда все элементы уже показаны, то кнопка скрывается. Примеры:

*Решение на JavaScript(jQuery). 100 элементов*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var list = $(".wrapper-boxes .box");
  var numToShow = 10; //сколько показывать элементов
  var button = $("button");
  var numInList = list.length;
  list.hide();
  if (numInList > numToShow) {
    button.show();
  }
  list.slice(0, numToShow).show();
  button.click(function() {
    var showing = list.filter(':visible').length;
    list.slice(showing - 1, showing + numToShow).fadeIn();
    var nowShowing = list.filter(':visible').length;
    if (nowShowing >= numInList) {
      button.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper-boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  counter-reset: albumList;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

button {
  width: 550px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}

.box:after {
  counter-increment: albumList;
  content: counter(albumList);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  padding: 4% 7%;
  border-radius: 5%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.33) inset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<button>Показать ещё 10</button>
```

*Другое количество элементов (не кратное десяти)*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var list = $(".wrapper-boxes .box");
  var numToShow = 10; //сколько показывать элементов
  var button = $("button");
  var numInList = list.length;
  list.hide();
  if (numInList > numToShow) {
    button.show();
  }
  list.slice(0, numToShow).show();
  button.click(function() {
    var showing = list.filter(':visible').length;
    list.slice(showing - 1, showing + numToShow).fadeIn();
    var nowShowing = list.filter(':visible').length;
    if (nowShowing >= numInList) {
      button.hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper-boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  counter-reset: albumList;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

button {
  width: 550px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}

.box:after {
  counter-increment: albumList;
  content: counter(albumList);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  padding: 4% 7%;
  border-radius: 5%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.33) inset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper-boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<button>Показать ещё 10</button>
```

*Решение на нативном JavaScript*

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  const limit = 10;
  const nextOpen = (wrapper, button) => {
    const boxs = wrapper.querySelectorAll(".box"),
      len = boxs.length - 2,
      endBox = wrapper.querySelector(".nextstop"),
      index = [...boxs].indexOf(endBox) + limit;
    if (endBox) endBox.classList.remove("nextstop");
    if (index < len) boxs[index].classList.add("nextstop");
    else button.remove()
  }
  document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper-boxes").forEach(wrapper => {
    const button = wrapper.nextElementSibling;
    button.addEventListener("click", nextOpen.bind(null, wrapper, button));
    nextOpen(wrapper, button);
  })
});
```

```css
.wrapper-boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  counter-reset: albumList;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

button {
  width: 550px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: orange;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
}

.box:after {
  counter-increment: albumList;
  content: counter(albumList);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  padding: 4% 7%;
  border-radius: 5%;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 2vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: monospace;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(34, 60, 80, 0.33) inset;
}

.box.nextstop~.box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-boxes">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<button>Показать ещё 10</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

- [codepen 1](https://codepen.io/contradvert/pen/RBGpKj)

  ```js
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".show-more-btn").click(function(e){
      $(".show-more-item:hidden").slice(0,3).fadeIn();
      if ($(".show-more-item:hidden").length < 1) $(this).fadeOut();
    })
  })
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="show-more-item">blah</div>
  <div class="show-more-item">blah</div>
  <div class="show-more-item">blah</div>
  <div class="show-more-item">blah</div>
  <div class="show-more-item" style="display: none;">blah</div>
  <div class="show-more-item" style="display: none;">blah</div>
  <div class="show-more-item" style="display: none;">blah</div>
  <div class="show-more-item" style="display: none;">blah</div>
  <div class="show-more-item" style="display: none;">blah</div>
  <div class="show-more-item" style="display: none;">blah</div>
  <div class="show-more-item" style="display: none;">blah</div>
  <div class="show-more-item" style="display: none;">blah</div>
  <div class="show-more-item" style="display: none;">blah</div>
  <div class="show-more-btn">Load More</div>
  ```
- [codepen 2](https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/YXRxqE)

  ```css
  * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    background: #e9ecef;
  }

  h3 {
    background: #1C1D1F;
    color: white;
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px auto;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  ul {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    background: white;
  }

  li {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-top: 1px solid #e9ecef;
  }

  ul a {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    transition: background .3s;
  }

  ul a:after {
    content: '⇢';
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
  }

  ul a:hover {
    background: #cdcbc4;
  }
  /* CHECKBOX CONTAINER STYLES
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

  .container {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    border-top: 0;
  }

  [type="checkbox"] {
    position: absolute;
    left: -9999px;
  }

  label {
    background: #e4e3df;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: top .45s cubic-bezier(.44, .99, .48, 1);
  }
  /*
   * use the rule below for testing purposes
   * label:hover {
   *    background: yellow;
   *  }
   */

  label:before,
  label:after {
    position: absolute;
  }

  label:before {
    content: 'More';
    left: 10px;
  }

  label:after {
    content: '⇣●';
    right: 10px;
    -webkit-animation: sudo .85s linear infinite alternate;
    animation: sudo .85s linear infinite alternate;
  }

  @keyframes sudo {
    from {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-2px);
      transform: translateY(-2px);
    }
    to {
      -webkit-transform: translateY(2px);
      transform: translateY(2px);
    }
  }

  input[type="checkbox"] ~ ul {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height .45s cubic-bezier(.44, .99, .48, 1);
  }
  /* CHECKED STATE STYLES
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– */

  [type="checkbox"]:checked ~ ul {
    /**
     * the value of the `max-height` property specifies the transition speed
     * set a very big value (e.g. 9999px) to see the difference
     */
    
    max-height: 300px;
  }

  [type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    top: 100%;
  }

  [type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
    content: 'Less';
  }

  [type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
    content: '⇡●';
  }

  ul li:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <h3>Pure CSS "Show More/Less" functionality with Transitions<br>(slideToggle effect with no JavaScript).</h3>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Four</a></li>
    <li class="container">
      <input type="checkbox" id="check_id">
      <label for="check_id"></label>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Five</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Six</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Seven</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eight</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nine</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ten</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  ```

Answer (score 2):

Кого интересует более проработанная версия, в адаптивных блоках в ряд 3 блока, плюс кнопка **показать еще** блоки с фото, показываем 6 блоков, но если надо подгрузить еще 6, нажимаем кнопку **показать еще**, если все фото загружены, кнопка исчезает. Код подгрузить еще блоки, позаимствовал у автора выше.

Для фото до и после, используется скрипт **twentytwenty**.

Таким способом можно показывать работы, до и после, ну и для другого применить.

```js
 //подгрузить еще по кнопке, если все элемнты подгружены, скрывает кнопку
 $(window).on('load', function() {
    initTwenty();
  });

  // Фото, до и после
  function initTwenty() {
    $(".twentytwenty").twentytwenty({
      no_overlay: false, // Не показывать наложение было, стало, true скрыть
      // Перемещать ползунок при наведении курсора мыши
      move_slider_on_hover: false, 
      // Разрешить пользователю проводить пальцем в любом месте
      // изображения для управления движением ползунка.
      move_with_handle_only: true, 
      before_label: 'До',
      after_label: 'После'
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    var list = $(".gggggggg .twentytwenty");
    var numToShow = 6; //сколько показывать элементов
    var button = $("button");
    var numInList = list.length;
    list.hide();
    if (numInList > numToShow) {
      button.show();
    }
    list.slice(0, numToShow).show();
    button.click(function() {
      var showing = list.filter(':visible').length;
      list.slice(showing - 1, showing + numToShow).fadeIn();
      var nowShowing = list.filter(':visible').length;
      if (nowShowing >= numInList) {
        button.hide();
      }
      initTwenty();
    });
  });
```

```css
.prfota {
  margin: 0 0 -40px -40px;
}
.twentytwenty-wrapper{
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 calc(33.333333% - 0px);
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.333333% - 0px);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.twentytwenty-container{
margin: 0 0 40px 40px;
}

.gggggggg button {
  width: 280px;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid #CB002B;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  color: #282725;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 90px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
.gggggggg button:hover {
  background: #282725;
  border: 1px solid #282725;
  color: #fff;
}

.wr {
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.prfota {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://test.vl-it.ru/media/twentytwenty/css/twentytwenty.css">
 <script src="https://test.vl-it.ru/media/twentytwenty/js/jquery.event.move.js"></script>
 <script src="https://test.vl-it.ru/media/twentytwenty/js/jquery.twentytwenty.js"></script>
 
 <div class="gggggggg">
   <div class="prfota wr prfot">
     <div class="twentytwenty">
       <img src="https://wallbox.ru/resize/1600x900/wallpapers/main2/201718/gory-skaly-more-vodopad-poselok.jpg" />
       <img src="https://www.bwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/KallurLighthouse-1600x900.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="twentytwenty">
       <img src="https://wallbox.ru/resize/1600x900/wallpapers/main2/201718/gory-skaly-more-vodopad-poselok.jpg" />
       <img src="https://www.bwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/KallurLighthouse-1600x900.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="twentytwenty">
       <img src="https://wallbox.ru/resize/1600x900/wallpapers/main2/201718/gory-skaly-more-vodopad-poselok.jpg" />
       <img src="https://www.bwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/KallurLighthouse-1600x900.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="twentytwenty">
       <img src="https://wallbox.ru/resize/1600x900/wallpapers/main2/201718/gory-skaly-more-vodopad-poselok.jpg" />
       <img src="https://www.bwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/KallurLighthouse-1600x900.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="twentytwenty">
       <img src="https://wallbox.ru/resize/1600x900/wallpapers/main2/201718/gory-skaly-more-vodopad-poselok.jpg" />
       <img src="https://www.bwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/KallurLighthouse-1600x900.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="twentytwenty">
       <img src="https://wallbox.ru/resize/1600x900/wallpapers/main2/201718/gory-skaly-more-vodopad-poselok.jpg" />
       <img src="https://www.bwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/KallurLighthouse-1600x900.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="twentytwenty">
       <img src="https://wallbox.ru/resize/1600x900/wallpapers/main2/201718/gory-skaly-more-vodopad-poselok.jpg" />
       <img src="https://www.bwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/KallurLighthouse-1600x900.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="twentytwenty">
       <img src="https://wallbox.ru/resize/1600x900/wallpapers/main2/201718/gory-skaly-more-vodopad-poselok.jpg" />
       <img src="https://www.bwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/KallurLighthouse-1600x900.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="twentytwenty">
       <img src="https://wallbox.ru/resize/1600x900/wallpapers/main2/201718/gory-skaly-more-vodopad-poselok.jpg" />
       <img src="https://www.bwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/KallurLighthouse-1600x900.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="twentytwenty">
       <img src="https://wallbox.ru/resize/1600x900/wallpapers/main2/201718/gory-skaly-more-vodopad-poselok.jpg" />
       <img src="https://www.bwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/KallurLighthouse-1600x900.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="twentytwenty">
       <img src="https://wallbox.ru/resize/1600x900/wallpapers/main2/201718/gory-skaly-more-vodopad-poselok.jpg" />
       <img src="https://www.bwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/KallurLighthouse-1600x900.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="twentytwenty">
       <img src="https://wallbox.ru/resize/1600x900/wallpapers/main2/201718/gory-skaly-more-vodopad-poselok.jpg" />
       <img src="https://www.bwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/KallurLighthouse-1600x900.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="twentytwenty">
       <img src="https://wallbox.ru/resize/1600x900/wallpapers/main2/201718/gory-skaly-more-vodopad-poselok.jpg" />
       <img src="https://www.bwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/KallurLighthouse-1600x900.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="twentytwenty">
       <img src="https://wallbox.ru/resize/1600x900/wallpapers/main2/201718/gory-skaly-more-vodopad-poselok.jpg" />
       <img src="https://www.bwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/KallurLighthouse-1600x900.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="twentytwenty">
       <img src="https://wallbox.ru/resize/1600x900/wallpapers/main2/201718/gory-skaly-more-vodopad-poselok.jpg" />
       <img src="https://www.bwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/KallurLighthouse-1600x900.jpg" />
     </div>
     <div class="twentytwenty">
       <img src="https://wallbox.ru/resize/1600x900/wallpapers/main2/201718/gory-skaly-more-vodopad-poselok.jpg" />
       <img src="https://www.bwallpaperhd.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/KallurLighthouse-1600x900.jpg" />
     </div>
   </div>

   <button>Показать еще</button>
 </div>
```